# displaying images from an array in a gui window using swing in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, awt

I am developing a program that will populate an array with 52 images of cards from a file.  I would like to display these images in a gui window.  This is for a program that will select five random card images and display them in a gui window. So, right now, i am trying to develop the part of the code which will display images from an array in a window and i am at a loss as to how to display png images in a jframe.  This is the code i have so far.  I used a system.out.println statement so i know that the array of 52 card images is populating correctly, however, i do not know how to display them properly in a window.

```
String[] cardsArray = new String[52];

for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    cardsArray[i] = "C:\\Users\\mike\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\card shuffler\\cards\\\"+String.valueOf(i+1)+".png";
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cardsArray));
```

additional note.  I have to use a jframe to display the results in a side by side layout.  I thought to use flowLayout to accomplish this, but, i a not sure how to pass in an array of images.  I have no problem doing it with a single image from a file.  I am using the code below as a guide.

```
JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame();

// create and assign a FlowLayout for myFrame
myJFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

// Create a label with an image icon
JLabel jlCSCI = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("CSCI.jpg"));

// add the Label to the frame 
myJFrame.add(jlCSCI); // Add thelabel to MyGridLayout

// set the title, size, location and exit behavior for the frame
myJFrame.setTitle("ImageIcon Demo");
myJFrame.setSize(240, 200);
myJFrame.setLocation(200, 100);
myJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// make the frame visible (activate the GUI frame)
myJFrame.setVisible(true);
```

I am not sure how to develop the statement that would utilize an array that i created within the program.

Comment: See my answer to this question for an example of displaying playing cards in a JFrame: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18995483/522444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
for (String imgName : cardsArray)
{
    myJFrame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgName)));
}
```

Hope this helps.

***EDIT:***

I simply added a `JLabel` with an `Icon` to the frame. The `ImageIcon` class is just an implementation of the `Icon` interface and it creates an icon by reading an image from file. Creating a JLabel with an Icon will display the icon instead of the text. You can also combine the text and the icon. For more info, check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html).

Comment: that statement works perfectly.  I understand that it is a for each statement and myJFrame.add adds an image; however, i am not really sure about the part in parentheses.  Would you mind providing a short explanation.  I do now want to use code that i do not completely understand.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: actually i figured it out.  I think i was just missing a for each statement when i tried to develop this.  THanks again.

Comment: @MichaelJames Added some explanation.